# Invite friends to an application - Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Previously my this code worked well but now it do nothing
I want to show an dialog then the user will be able to select some friends and invite them to use this application.
Now this code shows blank page.

```
<?php
include_once "fbmain.php";
if (isset($_REQUEST['ids'])){
echo "Invitation Sent";
    $string = "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href='{$fbconfig['appBaseUrl']}';</script>";
    echo $string;
}
else {
?>
 <fb:serverFbml style="width: 500px;">
 <script type="text/fbml">
  <fb:fbml>
      <fb:request-form
                action="<?=$fbconfig['baseUrl']?>/invite.php"
                target="_top"
                method="POST"
                invite="true"
                type= <?php echo $fbconfig['appname']; ?>
                content="I tried this and love this, what about you ? <fb:req-choice url='<?php echo $fbconfig['appBaseUrl']; ?>' label='Accept' />"
                >

                <fb:multi-friend-selector
                showborder="false"
                actiontext=<?php echo $fbconfig['appname' ]; ?>>
    </fb:request-form>
  </fb:fbml>
</script>
```

Comment: it rendered a blank page, NO ERROR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now to invite friends the only way is to use FB JS
the code

```
function showInvite()
{
<?php
if (strlen($fbconfig['appname' ])>50)
{
 $title = substr($fbconfig['appname' ],0,45);
 $title = $title . ' ...';
}
else
 $title = $fbconfig['appname' ];

if (strlen($fbconfig['appBaseUrl'])>200)
{
 $message = substr($fbconfig['appBaseUrl'],0,200);
 $message = 'I just love this App, now it\'s your turn to try it @ '.$message;
}
else
 $message ='I just love this App, now it"s your turn to try it @ '.$fbconfig['appBaseUrl'];
?>
 var r = FB.ui({ 
            method : 'apprequests',
            message: '<?php echo $message; ?>',
            title: '<?php echo $title; ?>',
           });
}
```

Comment: function showInvite() must be in script tag and it shows nothing when i call this function , i have changed appBaseUrl and appname according to my app settings

Comment: Facebook have changed their GRAPH API for inviting friends, in my case it shows `UNKNOWN ERROR OCCURRED` , and obviously showInvite should be in a script tag as it is a JS function. you need to add FB.JS too !

Answer (score 3):

Facebook has deprecated this legacy FBML plugin.  While it may still work for a while, you will want to upgrade to their new [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), which will be easier to get support for.  Also, I've noticed some other deprecated features stop working lately (yet they haven't officially been killed), so this may be the case.  But check the javascript console for any errors and post them.

Answer (score 1):

Try out code on this page, it would certainly help
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Seems like this is what you are looking for

```
<script>
   FB.init({
    appId  : 'APPID',
    });

   FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'My Great Request'});                       
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the pages source/html? Maybe there are some errors reporting.
You can also in PHP call `error_reporting(E_ALL);` which will enable all errors to be printed instead of being hidden.

Also, perhaps you could check your browsers JavaScript logs for errors.

In Internet Explorer 9 press <kbd>F12</kbd>

In Firefox download firebug.

In Chrome press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

```
function showInvite() {
    <?php
    if (strlen($fbconfig['appname']) > 50) {
        $title = substr($fbconfig['appname'], 0, 45);
        $title = $title . ' ...';
    } else $title = $fbconfig['appname'];

    if (strlen($fbconfig['appBaseUrl']) > 200) {
        $message = substr($fbconfig['appBaseUrl'], 0, 200);
        $message = 'I just love this App, now it\'s your turn to try it @ ' . $message;
    } else $message = 'I just love this App, now it"s your turn to try it @ ' . $fbconfig['appBaseUrl']; ?>

    var r = FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: '<?php echo $message; ?>',
        title: '<?php echo $title; ?>',
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to describe your code; how does it solve the problem? How does it differ from the answers from five years ago?